# Allow PIP dependencies within a Conda environment to use Conda packages

Tags: pip, conda, pyproject.toml

I currently have a scenario where if I install a pip package directly it uses the wrong build of the pip package. I wish to first install the package using conda which allows me to specify the build, and then install the pip package to use the package installed with conda. An example of the sort of environment.yml file I am looking for can be seen below.

```yaml
channels:
  - pytorch
  - nvidia
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - cudatoolkit=11.3
  - pytorch=*=*cuda*
  - pip
  - pip:
    - git+ssh://github.com/my_username/repo_name
```

The GitHub repository which I am attempting to install with pip is a clone of the [ultralytics/ultralytics](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics) repository with some minor modifications. A Conda environment was set up with mamba as a package and then activated. Then, when I run the following command:

`mamba env update --file environment.yml`

A version of pytorch is installed with conda with the desired build type (cuda), but then pip seems to install another pytorch version, one without cuda functionality, and then the package installed from the GitHub repository uses this package instead of the original one installed with Conda. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Not a canonical answer... There is a new tool that seems to be geared towards this kind of topics, maybe you have the resources to experiment with it: https://discuss.python.org/t/announcing-unidep-unified-conda-and-pip-dependency-management-via-pyproject-toml-or-requirements-yaml/42114